# Why does the overshoot exist when transmitter turns on?

Tags: transmitter, pll, power-amplifier, qam

I am implementing power amp. with 16-QAM. Because of issue on power consumption, I am using time division duplex (TDD). By TDD, the power amp. turns off if the carrier wave is not needed and vice versa.

As represented in the figure, PLL makes 4 output signals P0~P270 with 90 degrees difference each. When PA turns off, the switch between PLL and PA disables to block AC signals.

Here is the issue:

**There exist some overshoots when the power amp. turns on by TDD.**

Does anyone experienced this overshoot when the transmitter turns on? What would be the reason?

[image][image]

Comment: You need to show the exact and precise circuit you have used and not some prettified version because how can anyone say what happens without full details?

Comment: Check the supply rail with TX off and turning on. How well is it regulated?

Comment: Can you capture a waveform of those "overshoots" and add it to your question? Can you share your exact circuit?